# TTS for Indian languages

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I want to develop an Android application (using some library) which displays and reads text in Indian languages. Mainly in Devanagari (Sanskrit/Hindi/Marathi etc.) what would be the best way to go about it? Should i specify Phonetics for each word and feed it to Pico? Or can anyone please suggest a better and a simpler library. (Which even sounds natural).
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I've followed speech engines a bit over the past two decades, and I've noticed that good engines are modeled by folks who hold advanced degrees in linguistics. If you want to develop something great, and aren't a linguist, I would recommend you find one to collaborate.
If the diction of your target language is fairly consistent, you can probably write a tokenizer, similar to the one SAM used for English, but again, that's probably a task a linguist can specify much better than us programmers.

Comment: For displaying the text: https://code.google.com/p/indic-text-renderer

Comment: I dont wanna write a program for TTS. I want to use one! I meant by the question that can you suggest a library that does it for me

Comment: That's not what you asked. You might want to edit your question -- however, there's a good chance you'll be much more successful using searching the internet by yourself, than asking in an English-speaking forum, because chances are, if there's a library or existing module for it out there, it will be documented in the native language.

Comment: Thanks a lot very helpful!!! Indeed if you wouldn't have insulted me I Could never have found it out! If you don't wanna help You got a great option of not replying!

Answer (score 2):

This may work.... Try to customize your TTS Locale as

```
   Locale loc=new Locale("en","IN");
```

```
   tts.setLanguage(loc);
```